# What is an effective way to collect data in Java?

Tags: java, file

Scenario: I have a GUI with various components in which the user can choose options. I would like these options to be collected into a single place where then the user can send that information to me. What might be the most reasonable place to store the information?

EDITED:
The GUI is already made up of the parts containing the options that a user has. For example, one JComboBox gives a list of the options that one can choose. Then I got it to print as `System.out.println(User choice);` All the other components follow the same pattern; all the information is printed through `System.out.println();` Now instead of printing this way, I was looking for a reasonable place to write these informations.

Comment: Its too broad to answer the question. Will the user store at their end and send it to you offline or is that an online transaction where they store and you immediately get that?

Comment: I was planning on deploying this as a JAR. Therefore, the user will store at their end and send it to me.

Comment: Just give the user the ability to "export settings" (or whatever) and choose the target file manually?

Comment: How might I give the user this ability?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that will be used as a store.

Use an object of that class to store what the user does, say they click a button have a variable in that class that is an integer and represents how many times that button was clicked.

When the data is collected just send data from the store class to wherever you need to send it to.

Answer (score 0):

> options to be collected into a single place where then the user can
>   send that information to me

You have a lot of options, depending on what "send that information to me" looks like:

1. You can store information in a centralized relational database.  Clients connect to it and send information to be persisted.
2. You can serialize that data to the file system in some format (e.g. XML, JSON, etc.) and give users a mechanism for posting the data to a listener of some kind.  Or they can attach a text file to an email and send that to you, leaving the details of downloading, parsing, and storing up to you.

You say nothing about how you plan to get this data.  Have you thought about that?  You need to specify both ends of the transaction in order to get a meaningful, actionable answer.  Perhaps you should amend your question with more details.

UPDATE

So now we have some details:

1. The application will write a file to disk
2. Users will be expected to email to the OP as an attachment
3. The OP will save the attachments, correlating them to user IDs, and import them into Excel for further processing.

I'd recommend using .csv as the file format.  It's a simple text format you can easily import into Excel.

SMTP is the communication protocol.  The listener is the email server.

How will users email to you?  Will you be setting up an email account to do nothing but field these messages?

Comment: Nope, that's not what I had in mind.  It adds no information whatsoever.  If ten users have your Swing UI, and all of them print out their personal options, how do they get the information to you?  How will you deal with it once you get it?

Comment: Sorry about that. The users could simply attach the file containing their personal information to me. Once I get a bunch of files, I will organize it through Excel to play with the data. The way I'll deal with the data is irrelevant for I am just concerned about the program generating this text file containing the information.

Comment: Attach it to an email, then.  Is that right?  So you want a .csv file for easier importing into Excel?  So you'll add the user's ID and perhaps email address to your spreadsheet so you can track who sent what to you?  These are all important details, and you've only supplied them after prompting.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a *model* class to represent the GUI state:

```
public class Model
{
    private String name = "";

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

You can render this on the GUI with a JPanel, for example:

```
public class GuiPanel extends JPanel
{
    private final Model model;
    private final JTextField nameField;

    public GuiPanel(Model model)
    {
        this.model = model;

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        nameField = new JTextField(50);
        nameField.setText(model.getName());
        add(nameLabel);
        add(nameField);
    }

    public void init()
    {
        nameField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
            {
                updateModel();
            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                updateModel();
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
                updateModel();
            }
        });    
    }

    public void updateModel()
    {
        model.setName(nameField.getText());
    }
}
```

Notice that when the GUI changes, the changes are propagated to the model object. The state of the model can be serialized using something like XStream:

```
public class Serializer
{
    public String serialize(Model model)
    {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        return xstream.toXML(model);
    }

    public Model deserialize(String xml)
    {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        return (Model) xstream.fromXML(xml);
    }
}
```

Now, the panel can be shown on a JFrame like:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 100);

        final Model model = new Model();
        GuiPanel panel = new GuiPanel(model);
        panel.init();
        final Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
        JButton button = new JButton("Save");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String xml = serializer.serialize(model);
                // TODO: write str to disk
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, xml);
            }
        });

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }           
}
```